# Drag and Drop one element only in a Div

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

My code creates a certain amount of divs using the following code:

```
var Div = document.createElement('div');
Div.id = 'block#' + i + k;
Div.className = 'block';
Div.setAttribute("ondrop", "drop(this, event)");
Div.setAttribute("ondragenter", "return false;");
Div.setAttribute("ondragover", "return false;");
document.getElementById("frame").appendChild(Div);

var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
innerDiv.className = 'block-2';

Div.appendChild(innerDiv);
```

However, the "drop(this,event)" should only occur if the div is empty, so I should have a function that looks like this:

```
function doDrop(id)
{
      if (document.getElementById(id).firstChild)
      {
            // do nothing
      } else
      {
           // drop, so something like this
           drop(this, event)
      }

}
```

However, I'm not sure how I can call this "drop" function since I do not know how to refer to the "this" and the "event" that are its parameters.

Comment: why do you have # in the id?

Comment: you really should be using addEventLister to add events and not setAttribute.

Comment: onDrop, onDragenter, onDragover are nor attributes. You can not assign them as setAttribute. You have to add them as addEventListner.

Comment: The drag and drop work perfectly, however element can stack within the div, how do i make that function work that it does not drag and drop more than one element in the div